# Windows Family Safety - Even though I've allowed a specific website for School, it continuously asks me for permission

Tags: windows, security, whitelist

I have family safety set to block all websites except those I have whitelisted.  Problem is, every time he clicks on a link on that site for one of his classes (even though the base URL stays the same) it asks for permission again.  So daily, sometimes 10 times a day I have to give him permission for the site I already have white listed.  Is there a way to make a website and all it's sub-sites accessible with one whitelist entry?  It seems ludicrous that we have to "allow" every sub-site.